# MongoDB. Split embedded array to the chunks

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to achieve this structure.

```
{
  _id: 1,
  notes: [
    // 0 - 99
    [
      {
        _id: 1,
        text: "lorem"
      },
      {
        _id: 2,
        text: "lorem"
      }
      // {...}
      {
        _id: 99,
        text: "lorem"
      }
    ],
    // 100 - 199
    [
      {
        _id: 100,
        text: "lorem"
      },
      {
        _id: 101,
        text: "lorem"
      },
      // {...}
      {
        _id: 199,
        text: "lorem"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

As you can see I have array of notes, which is splitted to the chunks by 100. How I should run the `db.sample.update`, so if chunk length is less than 100 it would be inserted into this chunk, and if it is equal then it will create another chunk with range (100-199) and so on other chunks (200-299)? Thanks.

Comment: What should happen at element 200? Should continue to create a new chunk 
 for range 200-299?

Comment: Yes. I just read this article: https://www.morpheusdata.com/blog/2014-12-01-how-to-store-large-lists-in-mongodb. But I don't understand how to implement it.

Comment: The article is pretty older (2014), then I'm not sure if is still a good approach.

Comment: Just because it is old?

Comment: Later 2015 MongoDB has changed the storage-engine, that why I'm concern about the article that was written before that date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case your are putting an condition like "if the array length is less then **n**, then push the new chunk otherwise create a new Array and push the new chunk".

You can do this in two steps:

**try to find a document of specific <_id> where chunk has less then n=3 elements**

```
db.getCollection("test001").update (
  {_id: ObjectId("5b79353e737098b608de3002")},
  {"$push":   {"notes.$[v]": {_id: 6, text: "ok"}  }   },
  {   "arrayFilters": [ {"v.3": {$exists: false}} ]     }
)
```

This will $push the element {_id: 6, text: "ok"} if the chunk (v.3) do not exists so basically has less then 3 elements.

If the query fails (so there are no Array with less then 3 elements) then you must $push a new empty Array and run again that code.

In my opinion you can't do this process with one-atomic query, must be a two-step process.